# LdapConnection differences between JAVA and C#

Tags: c#, java, ldap, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am currently trying to convert a Java code into C# in order to establish a SSL LDAP connection.

In Java, I can specify the certificate's location with the following: `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "D:\\xnet\\ldap\\cacerts");`

What is the equivalent in C# ? How can I specify where the certificate is ? (LdapConnection.ClientCertificates being read-only)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ClientCertificates property is a CertificateCollection instance, you should be able to add a certificate to this collection:

`connection.ClientCertificates.Add(myCert);`

The X509Certificate would need to be loaded youself, normally from one of the Windows certificate stores, see [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) for details on how to load a certificate.